# How to remove a service from Watson?

Tags: ibm-watson

I have already added a service in Watson Studio, now I don't require it for the next project so how to remove the service via the Watson Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Watson Studio I don't believe there is a way. I imagine that you are using the cloud version, if so, then you can delete it through your ibm cloud (bluemix) dashboard. It's going be on a resource, probably on your default resource group.

If necessary, here is the URL to [ibm cloud](https://console.bluemix.net/dashboard)

[image: Dashboard - Remove Service]

Now, if instead of the Watson Studio service you are talking about a project on Watson Studio, then go to "Projects", and remove the project from there.

[image]